# JunOS: FPC Major error alarm

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, interface, juniper-mx, errors

I hope everyone is doing fine!

This morning I've run into a problem. My uplink interface went down for unknown reasons.

Upon checking system alarms I see this:

```
show system alarms
1 alarms currently active
Alarm time               Class  Description
2020-04-06 01:52:58 CDT  Major  FPC 0 Major Errors
```

I've never seen this kind of error and not sure what it should mean. Has anyone experienced this type of error?

After digging into logs I've found very interesting messages:

```
Apr  6 03:35:53  chi-corert01 fpc0 Failed to send non-PEC pfe TOD update to other PFEs. Error code: 1.
Apr  6 03:35:54  chi-corert01 fpc0 Packet send failed
```

I don't have physical access to a device.

Device: Juniper MX960

Any advice on troubleshooting?

Comment: If you have a JTAC plan, they might have more specific advice regarding this specific error.  In absence of that, I'd start by rebooting FPC 0.  If it doesn't normalize, your next best options are going to depend on what you have to work with, e.g. spares.  If you don't have spares, I'd power cycle the whole chassis (yes, can be a pain) and change slots (also a pain) before assuming the FPC is permanently faulty.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have JTAC plan. All the research I'm doing is leading to what you mentioned... Rebooting FPC 0 or power cycling chassis.

Comment: The syslog messages you've included may not be related to your issue.  You _should_ see a more specific syslog message in 'show log messages", chances are the message you're looking for would be near another message containing "FPC 0 Major Errors".  I can point you to exactly what the error means if you can find the correct syslog message.

Comment: Also, if you are monitoring using SNMP traps, chances are you'll have an associated trap for that FPC as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FPC Minor or Major errors always points to hardware errors. There are many types of Chips on FPC (MQCHIP, LUCHIP etc) depending on the FPC types. Usually due to some issue on these chips , these errors start to appear.

You could try some preliminary troubleshooting to fix the error by taking the FPC offline and then online using CLI :-

```
request chassis fpc offline slot 0
```

and after few seconds

```
request chassis fpc online slot 0
```

If this doesn't help , technical team has to go on site to try the following things:-

(1) Make FPC 0 Offline

(2) Take FPC 0 out from the chassis for few seconds (~15) and reinsert it back into chassis.

(3) Make FPC 0 Online again and Observe the chassis alarms (show chassis alarms)

If errors still persists , then it means errors cant be removed. You will have to replace the FPC 0 with new one.